# how to get a single gps fix in android?

Tags: android, service, gps

I have a program that requires a single GPS fix when a service is started. This is needed to tell an on location change when the last location is. How to get 1 single GPS fix in an android service?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-an/3145655#3145655) from another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive found a way! all i did was defined a boolean `StartUp` then made this true in oncreate then  `if (StartUp = true){
DistanceMoved=1000000f;
StartUp=false;}` this will work if your location is done with distance moved.